How to count children in DOMNodeList? PHP
I am trying to count children of a DOMNode. It appears to give wrong results when I use count vs traversing or the ->length property. As if text nodes are not counted.
Consider
<?php

$html = '<p>with <a>link</a> text</p>';

$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($html, LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED | LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD);

$paragraph = $dom->firstChild;
$count = 0;
foreach ($paragraph->childNodes as $childNode) {
    $count++;
}

echo count($paragraph->childNodes) . "\n";
echo $paragraph->childNodes->length . "\n";
echo $count . "\n";

And the output is:
1
3
3

Is this a bug in Countable implementation of DOMNodeList?

Seems to be dependent on the PHP version - everything up to 7.1.x gives me the same result as you're seeing, https://3v4l.org/AqkJX#v7.1.33 - from 7.2.0 on all the way up to the most current 8 version, I am getting 3-3-3, https://3v4l.org/AqkJX#v7.2.0

https://www.php.net/manual/en/domnodelist.count.php#122701 has a user comment saying to "Be careful with using this function (referring to DOMNodeList::count()) as it's not available for anything before PHP 7.2, use the length property instead." - count($someCountableInstance) is supposed to actually call the count method of $someCountableInstance, but if that didn't really exist for DOMNodeList before 7.2, then I suppose there must have been some "workaround" implemented to make count(DOMNodeList) not to fully blow up, but apparently it was faulty.

@CBroe There's no "workaround" needed - until PHP 8.0, you could use count() with a non-Countable object, and it would return 1 rather than giving an error. Not very useful, but not specific to this class. https://3v4l.org/7LtFP

@IMSoP wasn't aware of that, thanks. "Not very useful" - yeah, rather even counter-productive, I'd say.

So it is an old bug, then?

@ITgoldman Not even a bug, just a missing feature - nobody had made the class return a meaningful value, so count() just always returned 1.

The Countable implementation on the DOMNodeList class was added in PHP 7.2, which was released in November 2017:

PHP 7.2 Changelog
Feature Request
Implementation
Comparison of your example code in different PHP versions

Until that was added, using count() just returned the default value it returned for any non-Countable object, which is always 1. (Since PHP 8.0, there is no such default, objects that don't implement Countable return an error instead.)
This means that you are running a version of PHP which has reached end of life - the last version where this code will not give the correct result is PHP 7.1, which last had an official security release in December 2019.
If at all possible, you should be upgrading to a supported PHP version. If you are genuinely unable to do that, you need to be aware that a lot of examples you see, and libraries you try to use, will assume you are on a newer PHP version.

As far as I know, count() in the DOMNodeList doesn't count the number of items in the node list. Instead, it will return 1, indicating that the object is singular. (In some PHP versions, it might return 0).
On the other hand, the length property of DOMNodeList is the correct and reliable way to get the number of nodes in the list. ($paragraph->childNodes->length)

"indicating that the object is singular" - as opposed to - what? It appears to have behaved differently in PHP < 7.2, but the manual clearly states, "DOMNodeList::count — Get number of nodes in the list", and also "Returns the number of nodes in the list, which is identical to the length property."

True, but like in this case, echo count($paragraph->childNodes) returns one only. Not 3.  I had a similar case like this... One more thing he's using count(), which does not correctly count the items within the list unless the object implements the Countable interface. (in old verions)

This answer would have been correct 7 years ago, but PHP 7.2 came out in November 2017 and includes a correct implementation of Countable on this object. So in all supported versions of PHP, it will return the expected value.
